# NullPointerException while retrieving data in Reverse through ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

```
Statement createStatement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet executeQuery = createStatement.executeQuery("select * from stu");
executeQuery.afterLast();
while (executeQuery.previous()) {   //15th line<--exception occurs at this place after first record is retrieved
    int rollno = executeQuery.getInt(1);
    System.out.println("rollno " + rollno + " name " + executeQuery.getString(2));
    if (rollno == 1) {
        if (createStatement.executeUpdate("update stu set name=" + "'vinay'" + "where rollno=1") >= 1) {
            System.out.println("row updated");      
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> rollno 1 name vinay

row updated

//After first record is retrieved it throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.previous(ScrollableResultSet.java:630)
   at com.vk.db.ScrollableResultSet.main(ScrollableResultSet.java:15)
```

Comment: The "recycling" of `createStatement` you do here might be the cause of the issue

Comment: so how to make the code work fine?? plz. make some changes so that... it runs properly...

Comment: which line is line 15?

Comment: i made an comment... in code.. that line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of error is recycling statement object. Try this code/

```
   Statement createStatement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet executeQuery = createStatement.executeQuery("select id, name from stu");       
        executeQuery.afterLast();
        while (executeQuery.previous()) {   
            int rollno = executeQuery.getInt("id");
            System.out.println("rollno " + executeQuery.getString("id") + " name " + executeQuery.getString("name"));
            if (rollno == 1) {
                executeQuery.updateString("NAME", "new value");
                executeQuery.updateRow();
            }
        }
```

Note. A query cannot use `SELECT * from table`

Comment: why cant , select * from table?

Comment: Because of driver limitations. [Resultset Limitations and Downgrade Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28615)

Comment: is there any website, where i can find all the important note rules?  @arkadiusz

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
 executeQuery.afterLast();
```

with

```
executeQuery.last();
```

or use a while loop like

```
 while (executeQuery.next()) {
   code....
    }
```

Comment: plzz check the title... and the database table has more than one entry with  roll no 1... which we need to keep in mind...